# Finding a limit with logarithm function

Tags: calculus

Find the limit

> $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}(\log(ex))^{\frac{1}{\log x}}$$

I have the solution of this which goes like: 
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}(\log(ex))^{\frac{1}{\log x}} & = \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \left(\log(e) + \log(x) \right)^{\frac{1}{\log x}}\\
& = \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \left(1 + \log(x) \right)^{\frac{1}{\log x}}\\
& = e^{\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\log(x)}{\log(x)}}\\
& = e
\end{align}
I need the derivation of the property used in this solution. If somebody can detail me on this I will be greatful or let me know the source from where I can get derivation of results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the first step uses the property that
$$\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$$
The second step makes use of the fact that
$$\log(e) = 1$$
For the third step, note the following. Set $\log(x) = t$. Note that as $x \to 1$, we have $t \to 0$. Hence, the limit is
$$\lim_{t \to 0}(1+t)^{1/t}$$
which I trust you should be able to evaluate.